# JavaScript - overwriting .onload prototype of HTMLImageElement(s)

Tags: javascript, image, prototype, onload, overwrite

Is it possible to bind an **onload** event to each image, declaring it once? I tried, but can't manage to get it working... (this error is thrown: *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation*)

```
HTMLImageElement.prototype.onload = function()
{
        console.log(this, "loaded");
};
```

P.S: I also tried returning *this*, but doesn't seem to be the issue here... any suggestions / explanations on why my current code isn't working?

Comment: No. Don't mess with builtin prototypes.

Comment: http://www.ncyoung.com/?p=194

Comment: @Bergi It's an empty built-in prototype. It's an event listener, it's made for custom boundations of custom functions.

Comment: @mplungjan That's interesting, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Bilal075_ is does not matter if `onload`  exists for `HTMLImageElement.prototype` or not. You should never add custom functionality by modifying the prototype of native objects, and should avoid to do so for objects that you don't own (e.g. of foreign libraries), except if they give you a defined why how you should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a handler on the prototype, no.

In fact, I'm not aware of any way to get a proactive notification for image load if you haven't hooked `load` on the *specific* image element, since `load` doesn't bubble.

I only two know two ways to implement a general "some image somewhere has loaded" mechanism:

1. Use a timer loop, which is obviously unsatisfying on multiple levels. But it does function. The actual query (`document.getElementsByTagName("img")`) isn't that bad as it returns a reference to the *continually updated* (live) `HTMLCollection` of `img` elements, rather than creating a snapshot like `querySelectorAll` does. Then you can use `Array.prototype` methods on it (directly, to avoid creating an intermediary array, if you like).
2. Use a mutation observer to watch for new `img` elements being added or the `src` attribute on existing `img` elements changing, then hook up a `load` handler if their `complete` property isn't true. (You have to be careful with race conditions there; the property can be changed by the browser even while your JavaScript code is running, because your JavaScript code is running on a single UI thread, but the *browser* is multi-threaded.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried setting up a mutation Observer, but doesn't seem to be picking up the 'static' elements (the one which are written in the document itself). I've read about the mutation Observer, and is actually designed to detect changes in the current DOM.

Comment: @Bilal075_: Markup in the HTML becomes elements in the DOM (that's its purpose). If you went with the mutation observer approach, you'd need to start with a check for elements that already exist, and then use the observer to watch for new `img` elements or `img` elements whose `src` changes.

Comment: But how am I supposed to add onload listeners *(programmatically)* to these elements that have been in the HTML'S *'markup'* from the start?

Comment: @Bilal075_: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")` gives you an `HTMLCollection` of them. Call that from code included in a `script` tag at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag and setup handlers on the ones that aren't complete yet (some of them already will be), allowing for the race condition I mentioned above. Or if you want to catch them as they're added by the parser, set up the mutation observer in a `script` tag at the **top** of `body`, before any `<img>` tags are processed.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning your name, stackoverflow simply won't let me. But back to our discussion. My script is already set in the *<head>* tag, and is called as soon as the document has a **readystate** *interactive*. This basically means *that whenever the document is ready to interact with the client, he can / will*. As soon as this ready state hits, this function is called, and selects (as you mentioned as well) all the elements with the **IMG** tag. But setting an event listener on this collection, simply won't work. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Have the images been loaded already?

Comment: @Bilal075_: Can't help you with code I cannot see. :-) At this point we're well away from the original question. I suggest creating a [mcve] of the code you're having trouble with and posting it as a question.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error because `onload` is an accessor property defined in `HTMLElement.prototype`.

You are supposed to call the accessor only on HTML elements, but you are calling the setter on `HTMLImageElement.prototype`, which is not an HTML element.

If you want to define that function, use `defineProperty` instead.

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'onload', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  value: function () {
    console.log(this, "loaded");
  }
});
var img = new Image();
img.onload();
```

Warning: Messing with builtin prototypes is bad practice.

However, that only defines a function. The function won't be magically called when the image is loaded, even if the function is named `onload`.

That's because even listeners are internal things. It's not that, when an image is loaded, the browser calls the `onload` method. Instead, when you set the `onload` method, that function is internally stored as an event listener, and when the image is loaded the browser runs the `load` event listeners.

Instead, the proper way would be using Web Components to create a custom element:

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.getAttribute('src');
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('loaded');
  });
  this.appendChild(img);  
};
document.registerElement('my-img', {prototype: proto});
```

```html
<my-img src="/favicon.ico"></my-img>
```

There is not much browser support yet, though.

Comment: As T.J mentions, won't work either. I'm trying to setup a default onload behavior for every single image in the document. Any workarounds then?

Comment: @Oriol In your scenario, it does. But i'm trying to bind this event to static image-elements too (so these that are written in the **HTML** document itself, but doesn't have the onload event(s) attached). Any idea on how I can make your snippet work to my fulfilling?

Comment: @Oriol: You're directly *calling* `onload`. If the OP knew when to do that, they wouldn't need to do that. Try it just setting a `src` on that `img` and see if you get called (you won't).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe I didn't explain well. I am only fixing OP's code, which throws an error. But of course setting a function won't magically call it when a resource is loaded, even if you name it `onload`.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks for your answer. Creating custom elements is unfortunately no option for me at the moment... But.. do you mind giving me an explanation of why setting the **onload** *(statically)* works, but defining it as a 'default' behaviour, won't?

Comment: @Bilal075_ Do you mean in the HTML source? That works because then it's parsed as an event handler content attribute, which sets the event handler to an internal raw uncompiled handler, which appends the event handler processing algorithm to the list of event listeners. Something similar happens when you call the setter of the `onload` IDL attribute on a HTMLElement instance. But defining a function in `HTMLImageElement.prototype` won't add any event listener.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, exactly. Too bad that there is no *(crossbrowser)* work-around to 'auto'-attach this event to static / dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 1):

This provides a notification for any image loading, at least in Opera (Presto) and Firefox (haven't tried any other browser). The script tag is placed in the `HEAD` element so it is executed and the event listener installed before any of the body content is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if ((!e.target.tagName) || (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'img')) return;
    // do stuff here
}, true);
```

Of course, by changing the filtering on `tagName` it will also serve to respond to the loading of any other element that fires a load event, such as a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've written something similar some time ago to check if an image is loaded or not, and if not, show a default image. You can use the same approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // loop every image in the page
    $("img").each(function() {
        // naturalWidth is the actual width of the image
        // if 0, img is not loaded
        // or the loaded img's width is 0. if so, do further check
        if (this.naturalWidth === 0) { // not loaded
            this.dataset.src = this.src; // keep the original src
            this.src = "image404.jpg";
        } else {
            // loaded
        }
    });
});
```