# addeventlistener drop error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Tags: javascript, callback, drag-and-drop, html5sortable

I create new Object by function, and i create `sortable` method to use, but that have an error on callback function

```js
;"use strict";
(function(){
    function libJS(){};

    libJS.prototype = {
        loopElement : function(element, options, callback){
            var libObj = this;
            var goesCallback = function(element, options, callback){
                if (!!callback && libObj.isFunction(callback)) callback(element, options);
            };

            if (libObj.isElement(element)) goesCallback(element, options, callback);
            else if (libObj.isString(element) && /^(\.|\#)[\w\d\-_]+$/g.test(element)){
                if (/^\./g.test(element)){
                    element = document.getElementsByClassName(element.replace('.', ''));
                    var length = element.length || 0, i;
                    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) goesCallback(element[i], options, callback);
                }else{
                    element = document.getElementById(element.replace('#', ''));
                    if (!!element) goesCallback(element, options, callback);
                }
            }
        },

        isElement : function(element){
            // code check
            var f=(typeof HTMLElement === 'object' || false);
                f=(f && element instanceof HTMLElement);
                f=(f||(typeof element === 'object' && element.nodeType===1 && typeof element.nodeName === 'string'));
      return f;
        },

        isString : function(str){
            // code check
            return true;
        },

        isObject : function(obj){
            // code check
            return true;
        },

        isFunction : function(func){
            // code check
            return true;
        },

        token : function(length){
            // create token
            return 'random_string';
        },

        sortable : function(options){
            if ('draggable' in document.createElement('span')){
                var libObj = this;
                if (libObj.isObject(options)){
                    libObj.loopElement(options.element, options, function(element, options){
                        element.style.position = 'relative';
                        var childNodes = element.childNodes,
                            length = childNodes.length || 0, x;
                        for (x = 0; x < length; x++){
                            var item = childNodes[x];
                            if (item.nodeName !== '#text'){
                                item.id = 'libJS-' + libObj.token(12);
                                item.draggable = true;
                                item.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                                item.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease';
                                item.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event){
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    // some code
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        element.addEventListener('dragover', function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                        });
                        element.addEventListener('drop', function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                        });
                        console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop); // View Error
                    });
                }
            }else throw 'ERROR: libJS.sortable(): this browser not support drag and drop event!';
        }
    };
    window.libJs = new libJS();
})();

libJs.sortable({
   element : '.sorter'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .sorter{
                border: 1px solid green;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .sorter:after{
                display: block;
                content: '';
                clear: both;
            }
            .sorterItem{
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                width: 70px;
                height: 70px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .sorterItem img{
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                min-width:100px;
                min-height:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sorter">
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="sorterItem">
                <img src="/data/upload/noimage.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is an Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

That was in `goesCallback` function when I drag `.sorterItem` and i drop it. It can kill the browser.

So, in `sortable` method i have `console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)` to view Error at some line.

How to fix this error?

thank everyone.

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve with the `console.log`. Do you want to see the function? It looks like you cannot log most functions. I ran `var el = document.querySelector('.sorter'); for (let k of Object.keys(el.__proto__.__proto__)) { try { console.log(k, el.__proto__[k]); } catch (e) { } }` and that prints only a handful of functions: `onmouseenter`, `onmouseleave`, `click`, `drag` and `focus`. It would be good if you could explain what error you get *without* the `console.log`, because I don't get one.

Comment: @Justastudent , No, I don't want to see function. It seems that somebody has changed the content of my question, which makes it no longer what I want to ask. I'm handling the drop event but it could kill the browser, and I did the console.log () element to see but get the error. So i got console.log () to know the error at any given line

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do `console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)` as ondrop is an accessor-property.

**Accessor Properties?**  With reference to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331093/6611700)

> An accessor property is one that is defined in terms of getters and setters, not as a stored value that might be written to. The "pair of accessor functions" denotes the getter and the setter function.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39066379/6611700)

So basically by calling `console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)` you are invoking the element's `ondrop` getter function without proper [this context](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#why-this) which results in [Illegal Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743608/6611700) error.

**Code Example**
A javascript code example to illustrate the point

```js
var Person = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  get fullname() {
    return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname
  },
  set fullname(name) {
    this.firstname = name.split(' ')[0]
    this.lastname = name.split(' ')[1]
  }
}

console.log(Person.fullname) // will trigger the getter function 'fullname'

Person.fullname = "Jane Doe" // will trigger the setter function 'fullname'

console.log(Person.fullname) // logs Jane Doe
```

So when you call `console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)` you are essentially triggering the `ondrop` getter without a *valid context*.

### Update:

I guess what you wanted to do was to inspect why the Drag-events were not firing and you ended up putting a `console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)` which, as it's been already answered, caused the `IllegalInvocation` error, resulting in a totally different class of error then the one you were trying to debug!

The reason why your Drag events are not firing is the function call inside the handlers [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent that if the event goes unhandled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

In your case, the *default action* means the Drag-related functionality, which, you are (inadvertently) preventing from execution!

I suggest you read more about [HTML5 Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) on MDN.

Comment: It seems that somebody has changed the content of my question, which makes it no longer what I want to ask. I'm handling the drop event but it could kill the browser, and I did the console.log () element to see but get the error. So i got console.log () to know the error at any given line

Comment: Well according to the question, the error you posted `IllegalInvocationError` was caused due to the reasons mentioned in the answer, so IMO it's still correct... but having seen the old question I guess I know what problem you are facing so it's best if you ask a new question regarding the same

Answer (score 3):

The error "Illegal Invocation" means you are trying to call a callable function with the wrong context, the context being the object the method is called on. Let me break down the `console.log`:

```
console.log(element.__proto__.ondrop)
```

Here, you're trying to log `element.__proto__.ondrop`. First, let me explain `element.__proto__`. The accessor property on every object, [`Object.prototype.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is an accessor property that points to the prototype of that object and is used to resolve methods in the lookup chain. For example:

```js
function Person(name) { //This is a constructor function
  this.name = name; //Set the name to be part of the instance
} 
Person.prototype.sayName = function() { //A function on the prototype
  console.log(this.name);               //and is part of the instance
}

const bob = new Person("Bob");
console.log(bob.__proto__); //The __proto__ property refers to `Person.prototype`
                            //and will log the `Person.prototype` object
```

Here, `__proto__` of an instance refers to the `prototype` of the constructor that constructed the instance. Now, in your case, the `__proto__` of an element from the DOM would be something along the lines of the prototype of `HTMLDivElement` or something else depending on what type of element it is. For the purpose of this answer, we'll say it's a `div`.

Now, when you try to access the property `ondrop` of `HTMLDivElement`'s prototype, you get an illegal invocation **because you're trying to access `ondrop` statically from the `HTMLDivElement` prototype, not an actual `div` element**! This leads to the "wrong context" because you're trying to call the accessor on `HTMLDivElement.prototype`, not a `div` from the DOM!

To "fix this", don't access the `__proto__` key. If you want to access the element's `ondrop` property, just do `element.ondrop`.

Comment: It seems that somebody has changed the content of my question, which makes it no longer what I want to ask. I'm handling the drop event but it could kill the browser, and I did the console.log () element to see but get the error. So i got console.log () to know the error at any given line

Comment: @MrKen That was me, sorry about that. You're free to rollback the edit by clicking on the "Edited ...." above my name and scrolling to revision 7 and clicking rollback. I still don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish though.

Comment: I changed and add content

Comment: @MrKen What do you mean by "kill the browser"?

Comment: I can not continue anything on the browser, even closed

Comment: @MrKen Why would you ever do that?

Comment: I'm trying to do a sortable method, and when I try it, it's causing that. (Sorry, Why can not I tag you?)

Comment: @MrKen I understand, but why are writing code that'll potentially kill the browser in the first place? What are you doing that could possibly do that? I skimmed over the code and it doesn't seem like it would do that.